# Unable to remotely access MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am experiencing problems with mysql 5.1 at the moment and possibly due to that I am unable to connect.

The port that I am using for mysql is open (http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/)

All of a sudden i was unable to access mysql remotely, could be due to luck of memory or something similar?! I can put any user name and password and still same result.

I have no data in the log files to share, nothing is logged for some reason.

I have checked and mysqld does listen to correct port

When I telnet xx.xx.xx.xx xxxx I have following result

```
Trying xx.xx.xx.xx...
Connected to xx.xx.xx.xx.
Escape character is '^]'.
?
5.1.66-0+squeeze1l_k{KBI'(7y!1rlHc8,u^CConnection closed by foreign host.
```

"and see if you get the same ... if not then you've a problem with the server. if that works ok but you can't do the same from the client machine(s) then you've got a problem at the client end." (http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1625679.html) So this is a client problem

Answer (score 0):

By default remote access to the MySQL database server is disabled for security reasons. However, some time you need to provide remote access to database server from home or a web server.

[Please refer the link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html)

Comment: When i did telnet I had following result:Escape character is '^]'.
?
5.1.66-0+squeeze1l_k{KBI'(7y!1rlHc8,u^C

Answer (score 0):

That says that port 3306 was open to your machine.  It is a good way to test at a *low* level.

You also need to do

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbname.* TO 'application'@'my.host.com' IDENTIFIED BY 'pwd';
```

Notes:

- `skip_name_resolve` controls whether you can have a host name or need an IP address.
- If you have a "dynamic IP", doing the GRANT is temporary.
- It is better to allow access from the application only to the database `ON dbname.*` it needs to use.  Otherwise it is an extra avenue for hackers to get in and do naughty things.